# Log4j RollingFileAppender backup is not done

Tags: java, log4j2, rollingfileappender

The problem of my configuration logger is that fileappender overwrite the log file created when it reaches 1999MB and restart from blank file.

It's not done any backup of the file.

So when it reaches 1999MB the content is lost and the logger restart to write a blank file.

This is my appender:

```
function getMyLogger(){
    ...
    PatternLayout layout = new PatternLayout();
    layout.setConversionPattern("%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n");

    RollingFileAppender fileAppender = new RollingFileAppender(layout, filepath, true);
    fileAppender.setThreshold(Level.INFO);
    fileAppender.setMaxFileSize("1MB");
    fileAppender.setLayout(layout);
    fileAppender.setAppend(false);
    log.addAppender(fileAppender);
    fileAppender.setMaxBackupIndex(10);

    return log;
}
```

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Please check the version of log4j and update it in question. It seems like it is not log4j2.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [api](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/RollingFileAppender.html#setMaxBackupIndex(int)), you should `setMaxBackupIndex` for rolled files numbers, or else there would be no backup files.

Comment: That's by default 1. At least one backup will always be created.
 http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/logging/log4j/tags/v1_2_12_rc3/src/java/org/apache/log4j/RollingFileAppender.java

Comment: fileAppender.setMaxBackupIndex(10); but always rewrite the same file

Comment: @chuckskull  sorry indeed default is 1. I tried as PO's code, rolling is OK with 1 backup files.